# Keras custom loss function with different weights per example

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm trying to implement in Keras a custom loss function where each individual example (not class) has a different weight.

To be precise, given the usual **y_true** (eg. <1,1,0>) and **y_pred** (e.g. <1,0.2,0.8>), I'm trying to create **weights** (e.g. <0.81, 0.9, 1.0>) and use these with the **binary_crossentropy** loss function. I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K

def my_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    base_factor = 0.9
    num_examples = K.int_shape(y_true)[0]

    out = [ K.pow(base_factor, num_examples - i - 1) for i in range(num_examples) ]
    forgetting_factors = K.stack(out)

    return K.mean(
        forgetting_factors * K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred),
        axis=-1
    )
```

And works fine with this simple example:

```
y_true = K.variable( np.array([1,1,0]) )
y_pred = K.variable( np.array([1,0.2,0.8]) )
print K.eval(my_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred))
```

However, when I use it with `model.compile(loss=my_binary_crossentropy, ...)` I get the following error: `TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got NoneType`.

I have tried a few things. I replaced *K.int_shape* with *K_shape* and now getting: `TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got Tensor.` I further replaced *range()* with *K.arange()* and now getting: `TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn`.

Can anyone help me please? What am I missing? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`K.pow` can take a sequence of exponents as argument. So you can compute the exponents first, as a tensor (`[num_examples - 1, num_examples - 2, ..., 0]`), and then feed this tensor into `K.pow`. Here `num_examples` is basically just `K.shape(y_pred)[0]`, which is also a tensor.

```
def my_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    base_factor = 0.9
    num_examples = K.cast(K.shape(y_pred)[0], K.floatx())
    exponents = num_examples - K.arange(num_examples) - 1
    forgetting_factors = K.pow(base_factor, exponents)
    forgetting_factors = K.expand_dims(forgetting_factors, axis=-1)
    forgetting_factors = K.print_tensor(forgetting_factors)  # only for debugging

    loss = K.mean(
        forgetting_factors * K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred),
        axis=-1
    )
    loss = K.print_tensor(loss)  # only for debugging
    return loss
```

As an example, the output printed by the two `K.print_tensor` statements would be like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(100,)))
model.compile(loss=my_binary_crossentropy, optimizer='adam')

model.evaluate(np.zeros((3, 100)), np.ones(3), verbose=0)
[[0.809999943][0.9][1]]
[0.56144917 0.623832464 0.693147182]

model.evaluate(np.zeros((6, 100)), np.ones(6), verbose=0)
[[0.590489924][0.656099916][0.728999913]...]
[0.409296423 0.454773813 0.505304217...]
```

The numbers are not exact due to rounding errors. The `forgetting_factors` (first lines printed after `model.evaluate`) are indeed the powers of 0.9. You can also verify that the returned loss values decay by a factor of 0.9 (`0.623832464 = 0.693147182 * 0.9` and `0.56144917 = 0.693147182 * 0.9 ** 2`, etc).

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you also explain please why does it return a list (second lines printed after model.evaluate) instead of a single number i.e. the loss? To my understanding the final answer i.e. the loss is the last number in this list, is this correct?

Comment: The printed and returned `loss` variable contains sample-wise loss values. Keras loss functions return sample-wise loss, which will then be averaged (and multiplied by sample weights) internally.

Comment: E.g., in the first `model.evaluate()`, a batch containing 3 samples is passed in, so the `loss` variable would be a 1D-tensor of size 3.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I asked is because I’m trying to make a simple test to verify the code. Considering the example in my original post, using the original `binary_crossentropy` gives *1.0729587*. Using `my_binary_crossentropy` with `base_factor = 1.0` gives *[1.0729587 1.0729587 1.0729587]*. But setting `base_factor = 0.9` gives *[0.8690965 0.9656628 1.0729587]* while I'm expecting *1.019311*.

Comment: Umm, maybe I missed something, but why is it 1.019311? Do you want the weights to be `[0.81, 0.9, 1.0]` or `[0.9, 0.95, 1.0]`?

Comment: BTW, in your example, you should probably use `np.array([[1,1,0]])` instead of `np.array([1,1,0])`. In Keras loss functions, both `y_true` and `y_pred` are 2-dimensional.

Comment: With `base_factor = 1.0`, **cost = -1/3 * ( 0 + ln(0.2) + ln(0.2) ) = 1.07296**. With `base_factor = 0.9`, I want my weights to be **[0.81, 0.9, 1.0]** so the **cost = -1/3 * ( 0.81 * 0 + 0.9 * ln(0.2) + 1.0 * ln(0.2) ) = 1.019311**.

Comment: Ah I get it. You should be able to get an average value 1.019311 if you use 2D inputs. Also, the loss with `base_factor=1.0` would be `[0, 1.609438, 1.609438]`, not `[1.0729587 1.0729587 1.0729587]`.

Comment: There's a mistake in my previous comment. It should be `np.array([[1],[1],[0]])`.

Comment: THANK YOU. Indeed, I have reshaped my example to (3,1) so it's 2D now and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In tensorflow you first predefine you graph with tensors before you run it. So it's quite common that a function which works with numpy array won't work with tensorflow. In your case num_examples is the problem.

Imagine that in tensorflow this loss function will not be called every time you need it, instead this loss function will build the graph for calculating the loss function inside your graph when the model is trained.

So when keras wants to try to build your loss function inside tensorflow, your y_true is an abstract tensor which most likely will have None for your first shape because the batch_size isn't defined yet.

You have to rewrite your loss function in a way that you're not dependent on your batch_size => remove the variable num_examples